# Multiple 4k external monitors unsupported at full resolution on Dell XPS 13 9380

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, wayland

**Update:**

I've managed to get all 3 displays working in 4k, but I am unable to arrange them in a horizontal line. Running `xrandr` outputs this as the first line:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 7680 x 4320, maximum 8192 x 8192
```

This indicates to me that I can't exceed 8192 pixels horizontally. That makes the question: is this a configurable limit, or is it the max that X Windows supports for 1 "screen"? If it is the max, then how can I setup my monitors as separate X "screen"s?

**Background:**

I have a Dell XPS 13 9380 Developer Edition that shipped with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, it is configured with the 4k touchscreen. I also have 2 4k LG monitors that support USB-C input. If I plug both into my laptop at the same time, then I am unable to run all 3 displays at native (4k) resolution in an X11 session.

I have tried different monitors, inputs, and cables, so I don't think the monitors are at fault. I have tried different desktop environments and window managers (KDE Plasma and i3) so I don't think GNOME is at fault. This works under Wayland, so I don't think my hardware is at fault.

I think X11 is somehow limiting my max resolution. I can run a Wayland session on the laptop and all 3 displays work at full resolution. When I was running KDE Plasma, it said that I was trying to exceed my max resolution when I tried to set all 3 displays to 4k. The best I could do was 2 4k displays and the third at 1080p. On GNOME when I try to use all 3 displays at full resolution it makes all the displays blank, except I can see my mouse cursor at the edge of the laptop screen closest to the monitors.

With both external monitors connected and all displays enabled:

```bsh
# All displays are blank, except the mouse cursor on the laptop
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 3
 0: +*eDP-1 3840/294x2160/165+7680+0  eDP-1
 1: +DP-2 3840/600x2160/340+3840+0  DP-2
 2: +DP-1 3840/600x2160/340+0+0  DP-1
```

With both external monitors connected and the laptop screen disabled (via GNOME settings):

```bsh
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*DP-1 3840/600x2160/340+0+0  DP-1
 1: +DP-2 3840/600x2160/340+3840+0  DP-2
```